# double field = null while it really should not be

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

So i stumbled on a really weird problem, i'm making a program for riskanalysis and whenever i try and create a riskanalysis and fill in all the double fields 1 of them gets the value 'null' while it really should not get that. I checked everything from my C# code to my javascript code but i can't find any clue of why this is happening.

The field that is getting a null value is: "preSeriouness", the rest of the doubles are filled in the same way and are not null.

This is my controller create method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(int? mainRiskanalysisId, int? categoryId, int? zoneId, int? equipmentId, int? taskId, 
        string activity, string action, string descriptionPotentialRisk, int? dangerId, int? consequenceId, 
        int? dangerousEnergiesId, string preventionMeasures, string safetyProcedures, double? preSeriouness,
        double? preProbability, double? preExposure, double? preRiskDegree, double? preRiskCategory, IFormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {
            Riskanalysis riskanalysis = new Riskanalysis()
            {
                mainRiskanalysisId = mainRiskanalysisId,
                categoryId = categoryId, 
                zoneId = zoneId, 
                equipmentId = equipmentId,
                taskId = taskId,
                activity = activity,
                action = action,
                descriptionPotentialRisk = descriptionPotentialRisk,
                dangerId = dangerId,
                consequenceId = consequenceId,
                dangerousEnergiesId = dangerousEnergiesId,
                preventionMeasures = preventionMeasures,
                safetyProcedures = safetyProcedures,
                preSeriousness = preSeriouness,
                preProbability = preProbability,
                preExposure = preExposure,
                preRiskDegree = preRiskDegree,
                preRiskCategory = preRiskCategory
            };


            _manager.InsertRiskanalysis(riskanalysis);

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Create));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Heres my cshtml code:

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="preSeriousness" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="preSeriousness" id="preSeriousnessInput" class="form-control" type="text" value="0"/>
                <span asp-validation-for="preSeriousness" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
```

Please let me know if you need to see more code.

Comment: your posted code doesn't show why it has to be null BUT yes you have marked it as nullable and thus it can have null

Comment: @Rahul What other code should i post?

Comment: Not sure if this is your issue, but one is misspelled here: `preSeriousness = preSeriouness`

Comment: @MikeH Can' t believe it but that solved my issue, i was searching way too far. Thanks